# How to save groups of tabs in Edge or Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

I have several jobs. For each job, I often open few browser tabs with known URL:

- **Job 1**: `http://sth`,`http://sth2`,`http://sth3`
- **Job 2**: `http://sth4`, `http://sth5`, `http://sth6`, `http://sth7`

Each time opening the browser, how could we restore a specific group of tabs?

Is there any way to save a number of tabs into a group and I could open them *with correct order* by just a click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome has recently added grouping of tabs. Did you try that?

When you open Chrome, right click a tab and select 'add tab to new group' it will then give you further steps. This [blog post (Keep tabs on your tabs in Google Chrome)](https://blog.google/products/chrome/manage-tabs-with-google-chrome/) could help.

Comment: where is that grouping?    do u mean adding to bookmark?

Comment: When you open chrome, right click a tab and select 'add tab to new group' it will then give you further steps. This could help >  [chrome grouping of tabs](https://blog.google/products/chrome/manage-tabs-with-google-chrome/)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old and has an accepted answered, but it sounds more like you want bookmarks stored in folders. You can then right-click the required folder to open all the tabs contained within in the order they appear in the folder.

A middle-click opens that folder in the current window.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue on **Microsoft Edge** regarding **saving tabs along with their groupings**. Currently, there are two solutions:

1. Utilize the **Workspace feature** introduced in version 114. (Note that this requires connecting the browser to a Microsoft account to function.)

   - [Microsoft Edge Workspaces (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-workspaces)
2. Use the following **extension**, compatible with both **Chrome** and **Edge**, which can save your tabs along with their groupings for you:

   - [Tabox - Save and Share Tabs (chromewebstore.google.com)](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tabox-save-and-share-tab/bdbliblipiempfdkkkjohnecmeknnpoa)